# Disabling visible product don't work

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, products-management

if we disable a product currently visible on store, this is still visible anywhere on the frontend. No matter how many time we clear the cache.

Also, duplicating a product currently visible on the store, and saving it with the same properties, the duplicate product will not be displayed on the site.

Comment: Did you rebuild the indexes?

Comment: Do you have a caching mechanism such as Varnish that isn't cleared when you clear the Magento cache?

Comment: I'm gonna sa..y re-index.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate products are disabled by default, so you need to set them to enabled explicitly before saving them.

Overall it looks like an indexing problem. Reindex flat article index and price index, then clean the cache again.

Comment: yes i know, but the problem persist.